# Triple integral volume by equations

Tags: integration

I have trouble setting up a triple integral to find volume bound by equations, such as:

$$z = x^2 + 3;\quad y = 3 - x^2;\quad x + y = 2;\quad z = 0.$$

I'm not sure how to figure how to find the boundaries for the $z$-axis. How would I go about setting up the triple integral?

Comment: Let's pretend your floor is the $xy$ plane. Then $z=0$ is on the floor, and $z=x^2 +3$ is how high your upper surface lies. The remaining equations will dictate the "shadow" of your surface on the floor. Try sketching out the curves involving $x$ and $y$, plotting relevant intersections, to get a better idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $y=3-x^2$ and $x+y=2$. Set them equal to each other and find the intersection points. Namely, $3-x^2=2-x$ gives $x=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}2$. Our lower $x$-limit is $\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}2$ and our upper $x$-limit is $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2$.

Furthermore, $3-x^2 \ge 2-x$ on the interval $[\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}2,\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2]$. Our lower $y$-limit is $2-x$ and our upper $y$-limit is $3-x^2$.

We also see that our lower $z$-limit is $0$ and our upper $z$-limit is $x^2+3$.

Our volume $V$ is therefore represented by the triple integral $$V=\int_\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}2^\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2 \int_{2-x}^{3-x^2} \int_0^{x^2+3} dz \, dy \, dx.$$

Comment: Thanks, this really cleared things up for me! I took @zahbaz advice and sketched out the xy plane and I figured it out!